# Loading Property File from Filesystem in Jboss Fuse / Karaf throws Nullpointer

Tags: java, jboss, jbossfuse, karaf, property-files

I try to load a property file in Java running on JBossFuse/karaf.

The file is located at $[karaf.home]/etc/bean.properties

The Code is able to load properties inside the bundle fine, but now I try to exclude the properties from the project itself and the code throws a Nullpointer-Exception.

The Path is properly resolved on my development machine as

C:\Users\someone\devstudio\runtimes\jboss-fuse-6.3.0.redhat-135\etc\bean.properties

The property-File can be loaded in the blueprint-XML to configure beans, but to access the bean my code needs the CamelContext. As I have some static codeblocks that are accessed without an exchange/context/registry, I also wanted to be able to load the properties in Java.

Both the functions throw the NullPointerException and I guess, it is because the code runs in Fuse.

```
public static Properties getProperties(String location) {
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    InputStream input = null;

    try {
        input = PropertyLoader.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(location);
        prop.load(input);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        log.error("Error loading properties file from: " + location, ex);
        return null;
    } finally {
        if (input != null) {
            try {
                input.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                log.error(e);
            }
        }
    }
    return prop;
}

public static Properties getPropertiesFromFilesystem(String location) {
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    InputStream input = null;

    try {
        input = new FileInputStream(location);
        prop.load(input);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        log.error("Error loading properties file from: " + location, ex);
        return null;
    } finally {
        if (input != null) {
            try {
                input.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                log.error(e);
            }
        }
    }
    return prop;
}
```

The Exception:

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:434)[:1.8.0_91]
>           at java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:353)[:1.8.0_91]
>           at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:341)[:1.8.0_91]
>           at com.mycompany.util.PropertyLoader.getProperties(PropertyLoader.java:19)[319:camel-archetype-blueprint:0.0.14]
>           at com.mycompany.camel.blueprint.MyProcessor.process(MyProcessor.java:21)[319:camel-archetype-blueprint:0.0.14]
>           at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateSyncProcessor.process(DelegateSyncProcessor.java:63)[231:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630135]
>           at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)[231:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630135]
>           at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:468)[231:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630135]
>           at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:196)[231:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630135]
>           at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:121)[231:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630135]
>           at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83)[231:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630135]
>           at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:196)[231:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630135]
>           at org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer.sendTimerExchange(TimerConsumer.java:192)[231:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630135]
>           at org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer$1.run(TimerConsumer.java:76)[231:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630135]
>           at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)[:1.8.0_91]
>           at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)[:1.8.0_91]

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Given your comments, I strongly encourage you to read "OSGi in Action" book

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Do not** do that. You are looking for trouble.

1. Load properties the OSGi way (use .cfg as extension and a blueprint `property-placeholder` bean)
   You have the added benefit of getting notified if the file changes (if you wish)
2. Inject them in a bean EVEN IF you are using only static methods.
   Don't mix managed beans with unmanaged static code unless you know very well what you are doing.

If some "*static*" code requires properties means that it is *stateful*, and this class deserves to be instantiated to a bean.

Comment: Means I should get the current "property-bean" and pass it to an initialization? For example, I need the properties to define a database-connection

Comment: Yes, set the "property-bean" inside another bean. If you need database access, why don't you use a datasource?

Comment: @user2122552 see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43465689/configuring-database-connection-in-jboss-fuse/43476015#43476015

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are getting an NPE without a more complete example. If you need to use properties without a route, you should be using Camel's property placeholder facilities:

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_fuse/6.3/html/apache_camel_development_guide/basicprinciples#BasicPrinciples-PropPlaceholders